# CKEditor with bootstrap skin floats on top of grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, xpages

I've added ckeditor with a bootstrap skin ([Bootstrap skin](https://github.com/Kunstmaan/BootstrapCK4-Skin)) to a bootstrap form but it floats over the fields below. Anybody got some suggestions how to solve this?

I'm using row and formcontrol as style classes

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution set the height on the field to height:auto; because the form-control sets the height to 34px